# KeyEventArgs in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a problem to how to catch which key is pressed.  This is my code, but i cant get what key was pressed. I'm using KeyEventArgs for declaration of new variable and then comparing it.

```
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs k = null;
        if (e is KeyEventArgs)
        {
            k = (KeyEventArgs)e;
        }

        if (k.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // do something here
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

```
 [component_name].KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Key_Pressed_Method);
```

into the constructor of your Form. Then, you can define what you want to do in Key_Pressed_Method() method.

Answer (score 3):

`TextChanged` won't give you a `KeyEventArgs`. You want `KeyUp`, `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` instead. `KeyPress` gives you `KeyPressEventArgs` instead.

Comment: Thanks, and how can i  implement it in my function?

Comment: @DimitryAbramiani you can't inside the `TextChanged` event. You have to bind to one of those others.